# Create bitmap of a DOMElement Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I have a Webkit DOMElement, a div for example.
Now I want a renderized NSImage or NSBitmapImageRep of it.

It's like a screenshot of a DOMElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public API choices:

```
-[NSView cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:]
-[NSBitmapImageRep initWithFocusedViewRect:]
```

Private WebKit method:

```
-[DOMElement renderedImage]
```

Comment: renderedImage didn't work, in my case. My DOMElement is a SVG group <g>. It returns a NSImage without any representations.

Comment: I update my Webkit version. Now, private method works, thanks!

Comment: Believe `-renderedImage` was added in Safari/WebKit 4 if that helps.

Comment: How do you update the webkit version and how do you know what version do you have?

Comment: WebKit updates are delivered as part of Safari or OS updates. Probably he installed Safari 4.1 or 5.0