# NSCGImageSnapshotRep, how get bitmapData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I got a image with only one representation, and that was a `NSCGImageSnapshotRep`.

I tried `[NSCGImageSnapshotRep bitmapData]` but, the class has no selector for `bitmapData`.

Someone knows this class? How can I get the `bitmapData`?

---

I'm getting this NSImage from Webkit `[DOMElement renderedImage]`.

[Create bitmap of a DOMElement Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422346/create-bitmap-of-a-domelement-objective-c)

The correct use is `[NSBitmapImageRep representationUsingType:id properties:id]`, this means doesn't work in the case.

I didn't think about compatibily, I'll be glad to find a solution **10.5+** or **10.6+**.

Comment: Do you need 10.5 compatibility, or is 10.6-only a possibility?

Comment: NSCGImageSnapshotRep is a private subclass of NSImageRep. Unfortunately, it doesn't have the methods that a subclass of NSBitmapImageRep would. How are you creating this image, by reading it in from a file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NSImage *img = [DOMElement renderedImage] ;
[img lockFocus] ;
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, [img size].width, [img size].height)] ;
[img unlockFocus] ;

...

// don't forget when you are done with the rep:
[bitmapRep release] ;
```

Comment: This produces a 2x scaled image on retina displays. This answer worked for me, producing 1x images on retina displays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24063823/105717