# How To Save PNG file From NSImage (retina issues) The Right Way?

Tags: xcode, macos, save, png, retina

I am trying to save each image in an array as a .PNG file (also as the right size, without scaling up because of retina mac dpi issues) and can't seem to find a solution. NONE of the solutions at [How to save PNG file from NSImage (retina issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507170/how-to-save-png-file-from-nsimage-retina-issues) seem to be working for me. I've tried each one and each of them would still save a 72x72 file as 144x144 in retina .etc.

More specifically I am looking for an NSImage category (yes, I am working in the Mac environment)

I am trying to have the user Choose a directory to save them in and execute the saving of the images from array like this:

```
- (IBAction)saveImages:(id)sender {
    // Prepare Images that are checked and put them in an array
    [self prepareImages];

    if ([preparedImages count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"We have no preparedImages to save!");
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];
        [alert setMessageText:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Save Images Error Text")];
        [alert setInformativeText:NSLocalizedString(@"You have not selected any images to create.", @"Save Images Error Informative Text")];

        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
                          modalDelegate:self
                        didEndSelector:@selector(testDatabaseConnectionDidEnd:returnCode:
                                                   contextInfo:)
                            contextInfo:nil];
        return;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"We have prepared %lu images.", (unsigned long)[preparedImages count]);
    }

    // Save Dialog
    // Create a File Open Dialog class.
    //NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

    // Set array of file types
    NSArray *fileTypesArray;
    fileTypesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"gif", @"png", nil];

    // Enable options in the dialog.
    //[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    //[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypesArray];
    //[openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:TRUE];
    [panel setNameFieldStringValue:@"Images.png"];
    [panel setDirectoryURL:directoryPath];


    // Display the dialog box.  If the OK pressed,
    // process the files.
    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            NSLog(@"OK Button!");
            // create a file manager and grab the save panel's returned URL
            NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            directoryPath = [panel URL];
            [[self directoryLabel] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", directoryPath]];

            // then copy a previous file to the new location

            // copy item at URL was self.myURL
            // copy images that are created from array to this path


            for (NSImage *image in preparedImages) {
#warning Fix Copy Item At URL to copy image from preparedImages array to save each one
                NSString *imageName = image.name;
                NSString *imagePath = [[directoryPath absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

                //[manager copyItemAtURL:nil toURL:directoryPath error:nil];
                NSLog(@"Trying to write IMAGE: %@ to URL: %@", imageName, imagePath);
                //[image writePNGToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath] outputSizeInPixels:image.size error:nil];
                [self saveImage:image atPath:imagePath];
            }
            //[manager copyItemAtURL:nil toURL:directoryPath error:nil];


        }
    }];

    [preparedImages removeAllObjects];

    return;

}
```

one user attempted to answer his by using this NSImage category but it does not produce any file or PNG for me.

```
@interface NSImage (SSWPNGAdditions)

- (BOOL)writePNGToURL:(NSURL*)URL outputSizeInPixels:(NSSize)outputSizePx error:(NSError*__autoreleasing*)error;

@end

@implementation NSImage (SSWPNGAdditions)

- (BOOL)writePNGToURL:(NSURL*)URL outputSizeInPixels:(NSSize)outputSizePx error:(NSError*__autoreleasing*)error
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSImage* scalingImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:[self size] flipped:[self isFlipped] drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
        [self drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0) fromRect:dstRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
        return YES;
    }];
    NSRect proposedRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, outputSizePx.width, outputSizePx.height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    CGContextRef cgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, proposedRect.size.width, proposedRect.size.height, 8, 4*proposedRect.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    NSGraphicsContext* context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:cgContext flipped:NO];
    CGContextRelease(cgContext);
    CGImageRef cgImage = [scalingImage CGImageForProposedRect:&proposedRect context:context hints:nil];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(URL), kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, nil);
    if(!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination))
    {
        NSDictionary* details = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Error writing PNG image"};
        [details setValue:@"ran out of money" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SSWPNGAdditionsErrorDomain" code:10 userInfo:details];
        result = NO;
    }
    CFRelease(destination);
    return result;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had trouble with the answer provided in original [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507170/how-to-save-png-file-from-nsimage-retina-issues) too.  Further reading landed me on a [post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191427) by Erica Sadun related to debugging code for retina displays without a retina display.  She creates a bitmap of the desired size, then replaces the current drawing context (display based/retina influenced) with the generic one associated with the new bitmap.  She then renders the original image into the bitmap (using the generic graphics context).

I took her code and made a quick category on NSImage which seems to do the job for me.  After calling

```
NSBitmapImageRep *myRep = [myImage unscaledBitmapImageRep];
```

you should have a bitmap of the proper (original) dimensions, regardless of the type of physical display you started with.  From this point, you can call `representationUsingType:properties` on the unscaled bitmap to get whatever format you are looking to write out.

Here is my category (header omitted).  Note - you may need to expose the colorspace portion of the bitmap initializer.  This is the value that works for my particular case.

```
-(NSBitmapImageRep *)unscaledBitmapImageRep {

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                               initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                             pixelsWide:self.size.width
                                             pixelsHigh:self.size.height
                                          bitsPerSample:8
                                        samplesPerPixel:4
                                               hasAlpha:YES
                                               isPlanar:NO
                                         colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                            bytesPerRow:0
                                           bitsPerPixel:0];
    rep.size = self.size;

   [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
   [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:
            [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep]];

    [self drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0) 
             fromRect:NSZeroRect 
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver 
             fraction:1.0];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    return rep;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Thank **tad** & **SnowPaddler**.

For anyone who is not familiar with Cocoa and using Swift 4, you can view Swift 2 & Swift 3 version from edit history:

```
import Cocoa

func unscaledBitmapImageRep(forImage image: NSImage) -> NSBitmapImageRep {
    guard let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(
        bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
        pixelsWide: Int(image.size.width),
        pixelsHigh: Int(image.size.height),
        bitsPerSample: 8,
        samplesPerPixel: 4,
        hasAlpha: true,
        isPlanar: false,
        colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        bitsPerPixel: 0
        ) else {
            preconditionFailure()
    }

    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: rep)
    image.draw(at: .zero, from: .zero, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

    return rep
}

func writeImage(
    image: NSImage,
    usingType type: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType,
    withSizeInPixels size: NSSize?,
    to url: URL) throws {
    if let size = size {
        image.size = size
    }
    let rep = unscaledBitmapImageRep(forImage: image)

    guard let data = rep.representation(using: type, properties: [.compressionFactor: 1.0]) else {
        preconditionFailure()
    }

    try data.write(to: url)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tad - thank you very much for this code - I agonised over this for days!  It helped me write a file from a NSImage whilst keeping the resolution to 72DPI despite the retina display installed on my Mac.  For the benefit of others that want to save a NSImage to a file with a specific pixel size and type (PNG, JPG etc) with a resolution of 72 DPI, here is the code that worked for me. I found that you need to set the size of your image before calling unscaledBitmapImageRep for this to work.

```
-(void)saveImage:(NSImage *)image
     AsImageType:(NSBitmapImageFileType)imageType
         forSize:(NSSize)targetSize
          atPath:(NSString *)path
{
    image.size = targetSize;

    NSBitmapImageRep * rep = [image unscaledBitmapImageRep:targetSize];

    // Write the target image out to a file
    NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
    NSData *targetData = [rep representationUsingType:imageType properties:imageProps];
    [targetData writeToFile:path atomically: NO];

    return;
}
```

I have also included the source code for the category header and .m file below.

The NSImage+Scaling.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface NSImage (Scaling)

-(NSBitmapImageRep *)unscaledBitmapImageRep;

@end
```

And the NSImage+Scaling.m file:

```
#import "NSImage+Scaling.h"

#pragma mark - NSImage_Scaling
@implementation NSImage (Scaling)

-(NSBitmapImageRep *)unscaledBitmapImageRep
{

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                             initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                             pixelsWide:self.size.width
                             pixelsHigh:self.size.height
                             bitsPerSample:8
                             samplesPerPixel:4
                             hasAlpha:YES
                             isPlanar:NO
                             colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                             bytesPerRow:0
                             bitsPerPixel:0];

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:
    [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep]];    

    [self drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0)
             fromRect:NSZeroRect
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
             fraction:1.0];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    return rep;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same difficulties with saving an NSImage object to a PNG or JPG file, and I finally understood why...

Firstly, the code excerpt shown above works well:

```
import Cocoa

func unscaledBitmapImageRep(forImage image: NSImage) -> NSBitmapImageRep {
    guard let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(
        bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
        pixelsWide: Int(image.size.width),
        pixelsHigh: Int(image.size.height),
        bitsPerSample: 8,
        samplesPerPixel: 4,
        hasAlpha: true,
        isPlanar: false,
        colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        bitsPerPixel: 0
    ) else {
        preconditionFailure()
    }

    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: rep)
    image.draw(at: .zero, from: .zero, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

    return rep
}

func writeImage(
    image: NSImage,
    usingType type: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType,
    withSizeInPixels size: NSSize?,
    to url: URL) throws {
    if let size = size {
        image.size = size
    }
    let rep = unscaledBitmapImageRep(forImage: image)

    guard let data = rep.representation(using: type, properties:[.compressionFactor: 1.0]) else {
    preconditionFailure()
    }

    try data.write(to: url)
}
```

...However, since I am working with a Mac App that is Sandboxed, which as you know is a requirement for Apple App Store distribution, I noticed that I had to choose my destination directory with care as I was testing my preliminary code.

If I used a file URL by way of:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let documentPath = documentsURL.path
let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("TestImage.png")
```

filePath = file:///Users/Andrew/Library/Containers/Objects-and-Such.ColourSpace/Data/Documents/TestImage.png

...which works for sandboxed Apps, file saving won't work if I had chosen a directory such as Desktop:

filePath = file:///Users/Andrew/Library/Containers/Objects-and-Such.ColourSpace/Data/Desktop/TestImage.png

I hope this helps.